# Почему не грузится страница после редиректа?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Пытаюсь сделать мобильную версию сайта с поддоменом "m".

ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :redirect_to_mobile

  def redirect_to_mobile
    if mobile_browser? && !mobile_request?
      redirect_to  "m." + request.host_with_port.gsub(/^www\./, '') and return
    end
  end

  def mobile_browser?
    request.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] && request.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"][/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android)/]
  end
  helper_method :mobile_browser?

  def mobile_request?
    request.subdomain.split('.')[0] == 'm'
  end
  helper_method :mobile_request?
end
```

Редирект проходит по нужному адресу, но страница не загружается.
Использую эмулятор андроида из sdk, получаю "This site can`t be reached".

```
Started GET "/" for 192.168.1.47 at 2017-01-24 20:24:47 +0300
Cannot render console from 192.168.1.47! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"subdomain"=>""}
request.url: http://test.ru:3000/
ITS Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.1; Android SDK built for x86_64 Build/NPF26K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.135 Mobile Safari/537.36
Redirected to m.test.ru:3000
Filter chain halted as :redirect_to_mobile rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Если тот же адрес открыть вручную, все загружается корректно.

Comment: а если открыть в браузере и подменить user agent на нужный, то будет редирект?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Страница так же не грузится, но разница есть, в эмуляторе url в браузере меняется с test.ru на m.test.ru, в десктопном браузере с юзерагентом андроида вообще ничего не происходит.

Comment: попробуйте добавить //. вот так "//m."

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Ваш комментарий помог увидеть, что я пропустил. Добавил к редиректу "request.protocol", теперь работает.

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Comment: [Вы б лучше `URI` вооружились](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/URI.html), чем городить подобные велосипеды :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В конечном итоге косячный метод, в исправленном(рабочем) виде теперь выглядит так

```
def redirect_to_mobile
    if mobile_browser? && !mobile_request?
      redirect_to  request.protocol + "m." + request.host_with_port + request.path and return
    end
  end
```

Comment: Непонятно, это ответ или более новая версия неработающего кода? Поле "ответ" предназначено только для ответов.

Comment: @AK это исправленный код, который делает то, что мне было нужно.